# C++, ASM, and cout

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly, iostream, disassembly

I'm using VC++ to disassemble a very simple program I've written:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was hoping to shed some light on how cout works, but upon inspection, the resulting ASM points to an external source (I assume):

```
EXTRN __imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A
```

Is there a way to identify, from the above line, where specifically this points to, and how to access it?  Even still, how to read the above line?

Comment: Can you just step into that function call in the debugger and disassemble once you get there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to disassemble that. The MS sources of the streams are part of Visual Studio installation. See: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src"

Answer (score 0):

`cout` is provided by the C++ runtime. In the case of Visual C++ that would be MSVCPxxxx.dll (xxxx depending on the version and debug/release).

You can lookup that stuff by using something like "CFF Explorer" or "depedency walker" and look at the program import directory.